# Basic JavaScript Sort Above Mean and Below

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I am trying to write a JavaScript code that will take a users input and find the mean. Then it should put the numbers above the mean in a list and the numbers below the mean. Everything is working except for the sorting of the numbers below and above the mean. Than you for your help.

```
function getNums()
{
    var nums = new Array();
    var numAmt = prompt("How many data values do you have?");
    numAmt = parseInt(numAmt);
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<= numAmt - 1; i++)
    {
        nums[i]= prompt("Enter the data value number " + (i + 1));
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        sum += parseInt(nums[i]); 
        var avg = sum/nums.length;
    }       

    var big = 0;
    var small = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
    {  
        if (nums[i] > avg)
            big += parseInt(numbers[i]);  
        else
            small += parseInt(numbers[i]);  

        document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = "Your data: " + nums;
        document.getElementById('average').innerHTML =("The mean(average) of these numbers is: "  + avg.toFixed(2) +".<br>");
        document.getElementById('bigger').innerHTML = "Your data: " + big;
        document.getElementById('smaller').innerHTML = "Your data: " + small;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why do I keep seeing people doing `new Array()`

Comment: Read Chapter 3 in your text book...

Comment: You seem to be doing `number + number = number`

Comment: Your way of calculating `avg` seems off, if only because you calculate it inside the loop *just to throw it away* every next iteration. Move it outside the loop; not for correctness of your program (it will give the exact same result), but for Code Neatness' Sake.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally break this into two functions, one focused on "find the mean of this array", and another on "sort this array around a pivot."

```
function mean(arr) {
  var sum = arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
  });
  return sum / arr.length;
}

function pivotSort(arr, pivot) {
  var sorted = [];
  arr.forEach(function (val) {
    if (val >= pivot)
      sorted.push(val);
    else 
      sorted.unshift(val);
  });
}
```

The pivot sort is not even close to optimized, but heck, v8 is pretty quick nowadays.